# How to disable zoom in Thunderbird?

Tags: thunderbird

Messages can be zoomed by holding `Control` and scrolling the mouse wheel. Zoom level can be reseted in `View > Zoom > Reset`. How can I disable zooming completely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To disable zoom in Thunderbird follow these steps

1. Go to Tools->Options->Advanced->Config editor
2. Click `I'll be careful, I promise`
3. Type 'zoom', you will see `zoom.maxPercent` and `zoom.minPercent`
4. set them both to `100`
5. close the window
6. click `ok` in Options window

Comment: Full path is `Tools->Options->Advanced->*General*->Config editor`